# cplex sos type 1 add

Tags: cplex, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

So just one quick question - I'm trying to implement a SOS type 1 probelm in CPLEX.

When I look at the documentation I see the add function

```
add(self, type='1', SOS=SparsePair(ind = [0], val = [0.0]), name='')
Adds a special ordered set constraint to the problem.
```

found here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.SOSInterface-class.html#add

When I look at the documentation I understand everything except val. My idea of this SOS1 problem is really you are adding the constraint (assuming that all the variables are binary {0,1} that the sum of all the variables at less then or equal to 1. That is to say that either all variables are 0 or there is at most one 1. So since its a sum the val weights are all 1? How would it be anything else? I mention this because I have found a peice of source code that makes these weights 25,18 as seen below

```
def setproblemdata(p):
    p.objective.set_sense(p.objective.sense.maximize)

    p.linear_constraints.add(rhs=[20.0, 30.0, 0.0], senses="LLE")

    obj = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
    lb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0]
    ub = [40.0, cplex.infinity, cplex.infinity, 3.0]
    cols = [[[0, 1], [-1.0, 1.0]],
            [[0, 1, 2], [1.0, -3.0, 1.0]],
            [[0, 1], [1.0, 1.0]],
            [[0, 2], [10.0, -3.5]]]

    p.variables.add(obj=obj, lb=lb, ub=ub, columns=cols,
                    types="CIII", names=["0", "1", "2", "3"])
    p.SOS.add(type="1", SOS=[["2", "3"], [25.0, 18.0]])

    p.order.set([(1, 8, p.order.branch_direction.up),
                 ("3", 7, p.order.branch_direction.down)])
    p.order.write("mipex3.ord")

    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me quote CPLEX [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/sos/04_declare_members.html)

> Members of an SOS should be given unique weights that in turn define
>   the order of the variables in the set. (These unique weights are also
>   called reference row values.) Each of those ways of declaring SOS
>   members allows you to specify weights.

Comment: so it will branch starting from smallest weight to largest weights?

Comment: You could see : Using weights of the members in a Special Ordered Set (SOS) https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399945

Comment: Does SOS1 in CPLEX doing sum =1 or sum<=1. I would think it should be sum<=1, but your documentation is leading me to believe it is sum=1?

Comment: Hi SOS Type 1 is a set of variables where at most one variable may be non zero. Regards .